# Validations in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I have defined fieldsets for form in zend framework 2.

```
$this->add ( array (
            'name' => 'unitnumber',
            'options' => array (
                    'label' => 'Unit Number:'
            )
    ) );

    $this->add ( array (
            'name' => 'streetdirprefix',
            'options' => array (
                    'label' => 'Street Direction Prefix:'
            )
    ) );

    $this->add ( array (
            'name' => 'streetnumber',
            'options' => array (
                    'label' => 'Street Number:'
            )
    ) );
```

I want to set required field for unitnumber only. Not for other fields.

I have writen a function..

```
public function getInputFilterSpecification()
{
    return array (
        'name' => array(
            'required' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

But, It's asking to fill all the fields. Can anyone help me out in this. Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to provide an InputFilter for every single element. Even if the InputFilter for that one Element is an empty array! In your case, explicitly state that it is not required and that you would `allow_empty` values

Comment: Can you give me the example using above code? I mean how to write it.

Comment: name => [required:true], streetnumber => [required:false, allow_empty:true], streetbla => [required:false, allow_empty:true]

Answer (score 1):

```
$inputFilter->add(array(
            'name'     => 'artist',
            'required' => true,
            'filters'  => array(
                array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
            ),
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array(
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 1,
                        'max'      => 100,
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

**References**:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html
http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.input-filter.intro.html

Answer (score 0):

In Zend 2, the "InputFilter" works more like in "strict" mode.

i.e. It requires you to specify if the elements mentioned in the InputFilter should have the 'required' value as TRUE or FALSE.

```
$this->add ( array (
        'name' => 'unitnumber',
        'required' => true,                   //Code Added
        'options' => array (
                'label' => 'Unit Number:'
        )
));

$this->add ( array (
        'name' => 'streetdirprefix',
        'required' => false,                   //Code Added
        'options' => array (
                'label' => 'Street Direction Prefix:'
        )
));

$this->add ( array (
        'name' => 'streetnumber',
        'required' => false,                   //Code Added
        'options' => array (
                'label' => 'Street Number:'
        )
));
```